# Android Studio: Where is the Compiler Error Output Window?

Tags: gradle, android-studio

When I 'Run' my project in Android Studio, in the 'Messages' window, I get:

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':play01:compileDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

It says `> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`
So where is the "compiler error output"? And/Or how do I run with `--stacktrace` option?

Comment: I run Android Studio 1.3.2 and none of the solutions work.

Comment: sucki android studio demands such silly questions to be upvoted.. :)

Comment: maybe it's the idea of IDEA to hide errors ideally (SCNR)

Comment: I have also same issue when i update plugin . I use Android Studio 3.4 Canary 6

Comment: I have also faced this issue. In my case, The problem lie in entity class data. If your data members are private them must create getter and setter methods. Due to this method other binding issues are coming.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**This answer is outdated. [For Android 3.1 Studio go to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633956/android-studio-where-is-the-compiler-error-output-window/48005426#48005426)**

One thing you can do is deactivate the external build. To do so click on "compiler settings icon" in the "Messages Make" panel that appears when you have an error. You can also open the compiler settings by going to File -> Settings -> Compiler. (Thanx to @maxgalbu for this tip).

[image]

Uncheck "Use External build"

[image]

And you will see the errors in the console

EDIT: After returning to "internal build" again you may get some errors, you can solve them this way: [Android Studio: disabling "External build" to display error output create duplicate class errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108393/android-studio-disabling-external-build-to-display-error-output-create-duplic/17220509#17220509)

Comment: Unchecking "Use External Build" introduces two errors when I try to build my project: `error: duplicate class: com.moberg.colorgame.BuildConfig` and `error: duplicate class: com.moberg.colorgame.R`

Comment: @Moberg Same problem here, I started a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108393/android-studio-disabling-external-build-to-display-error-output-create-duplic

Comment: Ok, I'm going to see what happens and reply in the new question if I find something.

Comment: I don't have that "messages make" panel... wtf?

Comment: Thanks. I found an easier way to open the compiler options window: just go to preferences -> compiler, it's the same window

Comment: I do not see these options now. I am running Android Studio 1.2.1.1

Answer (score 565):

For Android Studio 3.1, select the icon below the Build one in the Build window.

[image: Android Studio 3.1 raw log toggle button]

By Android Studio 3.3 (possibly in 3.2.1), the icon has changed, though the location is the same:

[image: Android Studio 3.3 raw log toggle button]

The build window should open when you run a build action (e.g. from the Build menu). If you don't see it, you can try the "Build" button along the bottom of the window (also visible in the above screenshots), or through the menus View → Tool Windows → Build.

Comment: Nice to see that so many has voted for this answer, and Android Studio 3.1 is still in beta 3. :-)

Comment: What Icon is that, I can't seem to find it, nor can I find a build window

Comment: It's sad that I had to google and dig through stackoverflow to find out how to see the compiler output. Thank you @boiledwater

Comment: @shikharbansal in case the image link ever breaks again, the icon is on the left edge of the build window. It looks kind of like a list view separated from "ab" by a slash.

Comment: Android's IDE simply says "toggle view".. toggle view of what ? +1 for this answer. Google still doing their best to obscure workflow for developers

Comment: I am android programmer for two years and I never knew this exists

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been struggling with this issue for like four months... Million thanks,

Comment: Thanks bro, finally among the many answers your answer saved me:)

Comment: There seems to be no such icon in AS 4.0

Comment: that Icon is missing on Android studio 4.0

Comment: in AS 4.0, that icon is AWOL. It seems we are left to manually run the offending Gradle Task from the Gradle Tasks pane, then the Build log will display the log that the previous build log was referring to o.0

Answer (score 47):

It's really straightforward to set up! Just go to the **Compiler** settings at Android Studio 2.2.3 and set the `--stacktrace` command:

[image: Compiler settings to add --stacktrace command]

Then run the app again

Comment: If it were really straightforward like you say, this thread wouldn't exist.

Comment: @jungledev it's really straightforward to set up, but it is not too obvious to know it :) Changing wording in my answer to make this clear

Comment: In AS 4.0, I set this --stacktrace.  But where is the output?  That was the original question.

Comment: @SteveWhite in the output of the console while building.

Comment: Antonio, the expected output never appeared in the build console for me.  I had to run gradlew by hand, as explained elsewhere on this page.

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know @SteveWhite. Maybe my solution is already out-of-date and not working. I haven't tried it myself lately, but if I come to do it again, I'll update this answer if needed

Answer (score 32):

Are you on Windows? Launch cmd, find your project folder and run "gradlew build". This should already give you more output than the IDE, you can also use --info, --stacktrace and --debug there.

Comment: beautiful! Now if only that output could be integrated into the Android Studio

Comment: My thoughts exactly. An IDE without a window for compiler errors? I bet we are missing something, but this workaround should be enough until that's addressed.

Comment: "Are you on windows?" - This also works under Ubuntu Linux too! Thanks!
`/[folder-where-you-installed-the-android-studio]/sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper/gradlew build`

Comment: I'm in the process of migrating a huge project from Eclipse to Android Studio. Best advise so far: get the command line gradle build working first, then worry about the new IDE.

Answer (score 19):

In my case I prefer to open the **Terminal window on the bottom left**, and run `gradlew build --info` :

[image]

Comment: @Pamblam Use ./gradlew

Comment: This is the only answer I found on this page that works in AS 4.0

Answer (score 18):

You can also see the error in the Build window by clicking on the toggle button.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

### For Android Studio v4.0

As others have mentioned, the "Messages" window that was evidently present in AS 3.* no longer exists in 4.0 (or else it's hidden very, very well). After wasting far too much time on this, I've found another way to view those compile errors:

1. Open your Gradle tool window. By default, it's on the right edge toward the top:

[image]

If you don't see it there, use View > Tool Windows > Gradle.

2. In the Gradle window, open your app's root option and run Tasks > build > build:

[image]

3. The Run tool window should open automatically, where you'll see details about the cause of the build error:

[image]

If it doesn't open automatically, you can access it through View > Tool Windows > Run.

Hopefully that gives you all the info you need. If not though, try:

4. Go to File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler. In the Command-line Options, add `--scan`.

[image]

Apply and OK, then try the Gradle build over again.

Comment: In Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 to see "build" command it should be manually enabled in Experimental Settings  (Preferences -> Experimental -> Configure all Gradle tasks during Gradle Sync). However, after enabling and adding `--scan`` command line option I still can't see cause of the error

Answer (score 9):

In android studio 2.2.3 you can find output in the gradle console as shown below
[image: gradle console]

Comment: In AS 4.0, where is this Gradle Console?

Answer (score 6):

I am building on what Jorge recommended.
Goto File->Settings->compiler.

Here you will see a field to add compiler options where you plug in --stacktrace

Comment: I tried this in AS 4.0.  I don't know were to look for any output it might have produced.

Answer (score 5):

Run

```
gradlew --stacktrace
```

in a terminal to see the full report

for me it was

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>       javacTask: source release 1.8 requires target release 1.8

so i added

```
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

in app.gradle file / android
and the build completed successfully

Comment: When I do this in a terminal (within the project folder), it says
   BUILD SUCCESSFUL
But when I build with Build -> Make Project, I see the same notice that there were compilation errors.

Comment: I dont have gradlew installed am i supposed to install a third party app just to check logs

Comment: you don't need to install anything, the file [gradlew] exists in the project main directory just run it.

Comment: i missed this ( targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 ) 
thank you its work

Answer (score 4):

Just click on the "Build" node in the Build Output

[image]

From some reason the "Compilation failed" node just started being automatically selected and for that the description window is very unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in android studio 3.1, Verify if file->Project Structure -> Source compatibility is empty. it should not have 1.8 set.

then press ok, the project will sync and error will disappear.

Comment: The question was not how to make the error go away.  The question was how to see the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i had a findViewById reference to a view i had deleted in xml

if you are running AS 3.1 and above:

1. go to Settings > Build, Execution and Deployment > compiler
2. add --stacktrace to the command line options, click apply and ok
3. At the bottom of AS click on Console/Build(If you use the stable version 3.1.2 and above) expand the panel and run your app again.

you should see the full stacktrace in the expanded view and the specific error.

Comment: This is AS 4.0.  It still fails the same way.  No stacktrace.

Comment: Did you add the --stacktrack --debug --info flags ?

Comment: Sure.  But that wasn't the problem.  The problem (near as I can tell) there is no longer a window where the stack trace appears.  However, it is possible to run gradlew by hand in a terminal to get the info.  In another comment on this page, I said which method worked.

Answer (score 0):

after the convert android to androidx.

change Import library problem will sol. 
Like this:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;  <<  like this
```

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;  <<  like this

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;   <<  like this

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;     <<  like this

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;      <<  like this

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;       <<  like this

Comment: This does not address the OP's question: how to see the compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps!

1. Go to File
2. Then click on Settings
3. Then under "Build, Execution, Deployment" go to Compiler
4. Add this in "Command-line Options" and press OK
   [image]
5. Now normally run your test/app again and when you will encounter error this time, you will see highlighted messages like this :
   [image]

6. Clicking on "Run with --scan" or "Run with --stacktrace" will give error in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2023/2024: this is quite an old question, but for people having this issue in late 2023 the main conclusion from all the answers here and my personal experience is that it's an Android Studio bug that is unable, for some odd reason, to identify an unresolved import which causes the build to fail. The challenge here is to identify manually which import it is that's failing since your IDE friend is leaving you alone at the ring.

You will need to manually go over all of your recent changes backwards until the last point the compilation work and check your imports for a red one which can't be resolved and fix it.

There seems to be multiple reasons causing this issue but it seems to be generally speaking a rare one. For me I was dealing with a couple of conflicts harder than a usual fight between left and right wing political argument. For other people it will be some refactoring in Navigation Component that is not covered by traditional Android Studio refactoring mechanism. Quite annoying, but should not happen often.

Answer (score -3):

I solved this error "Compilation failed to see the compiler error output for details"

The solution is very Simple:   Add in a Gradle below a line of code

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'

Comment: Where exactly is the line of code supposed to be added? Could you rephrase?

Comment: This does not answer the original question: how to see the compiler error messages.