# Android Studio Compiler Error

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to compile my project with Android Studio but if I compile the app this error appers:

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':LehrerOrganizerPro:compileDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to    get more log output.
```

What do I have to do so I can compile my apps with Android Studio?

Comment: I had the same problem. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633956/android-studio-where-is-the-error-output-window

Comment: It says I have not set the JAVA_HOME variable. I'm on WIndows 7x64 what should I do?

Comment: set JAVA_HOME: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7

Comment: does not help. I set my `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7` but the same error appears. That is the same folder which is in Eclipse under `Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs`

Comment: set JAVA_HOME to the JDK, not JRE

Comment: I set it to an JDK. I restarted and now the cmd gives an other exception - I think the location is right now. I gives me a code line from my project. But if I compile in Android Stuido the same error appears. The error now is: `*MY CODE* cannot find symbol :LehrerOrganizerPro:compileDebug FAILD`

Comment: well, you gotta fix that line of code. Post it here if you like.