# How to turn off Preferences > Compiles > User External Build?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I got the problem with android studio where every thing is in red and says "Cannot resolve symbol "xxxxx" ".....

I have  searched on google and I found an answer in this forum. THe answer said: **Turn off Preferences > Compiler > User External Build**.... where the hell is that ?? I can't find it anywhere!!

I've searched on the settings windwos by the compiler section, and nowhere was this "Use Externale Build!!"

Please guys help me, where is this option

Edited New:

In this link: [Android Studio: Where is the Error Output Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633956/android-studio-where-is-the-error-output-window), it is a tutorial (with photos) hwo to uncheck Use External Build. And I went through this tutorial but the User External Build option wasn't on the window!

Here are some infos about my android studio:

**Android Studio (I/O) Preview 0.2.3**

*Build #AI-130.762670, built on 1 August 2013*

**JRE: 1.7.0_25**

*VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM by Oracle Corporation*

Answer (score 3):

This option has been removed since Android-Studio 0.2.1. i.e. you cannot deactivate external build anymore.

Here are the related release notes: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio021released