# Android Studio: How do I show compiler errors when using the external compiler?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

According to [ben75 when answering this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203450/how-to-turn-off-preferences-compiles-user-external-build) it's no longer possible to disable the external build once it's been enabled in Android Studio.  But once in the external build I can't figure out where compiler errors are showing up.  Pressing Command-0 does nothing.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633956/android-studio-where-is-the-error-output-window) has the same problem but the solution was to disable the external build which is now impossible.  Help?  I don't know how to see the compiler errors.