# Showing java compiler output android studio 0.3.2

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, output

How do you show the compiler output in Android Studio ?

I'm using Android Studio 0.3.2 on Mac OSX Maveriks.

For screenshot see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9chGr.jpg

Related, but the option isn't available on my Android Studio: [Android Studio: Where is the Compiler Error Output Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633956/android-studio-where-is-the-error-output-window)

Answer (score 0):

Since Android studio 0.3.4 you can enable showin gradle output in gradle console tab.

In settings open: Compiler -> Gradle -> Use in-build process

you can find more [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio034released)