# Can't release without runProguard false in Android Studio

Tags: android, proguard

I tried uploading my apk to Googleplay because of this.

> You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a
>   zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.

So I added buildtypes for using zipalign with proguard in build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            zipAlign true
        }
    }
```

but I got this error code during making signed apk file.

> Generate signed APK: Errors while building apk, see messages tool
>   window for list of errors.

so I tried building signed apk with setting runProguard false, actually it worked.

but **I really wondering why I couldn't make signed apk with Proguard.**

Comment: did you check the messages tool window for list of errors?

Comment: yeah i tried, but couldn't find it. Would you tell about where it is?

Comment: I guess that it is there (if nothing changed): http://stackoverflow.com/a/16876993/2545832

Answer (score 1):

Check the location and path to the key signature.