# Can't get the binding auto generated class to work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

So I started a new project, mostly copying the architecture from https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvvm-architecture

I have it all almost compiling, I think, but for some reason my `LoginActivityBinding` class isn't found at compile time even though the IDE seems to find it, it doesn't show me red text and I can do control+b and it takes me to the layout file.

This is my class:

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity<LoginActivityBinding, LoginViewModel> implements LoginNavigator {

    @Inject
    LoginViewModel loginViewModel;

    LoginActivityBinding loginActivityBinding;

    public static Intent getStartIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loginActivityBinding = getViewDataBinding();
        loginViewModel.setNavigator(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void openMainActivity() {
        /*
        Intent intent = MainActivity.getStartIntent(LoginActivity.this);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();*/
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(Throwable throwable) {
        // handle error
    }

    @Override
    public void login() {
      /*  String email = activityLoginBinding.etEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = activityLoginBinding.etPassword.getText().toString();
        if (loginViewModel.isEmailAndPasswordValid(email, password)) {
            hideKeyboard();
            loginViewModel.login(email, password);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.invalid_email_password), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public LoginViewModel getViewModel() {
        return loginViewModel;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBindingVariable() {
        return BR.viewModel;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.login_activity;
    }

}
```

This is the `BaseActivity` it extends:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity<T extends ViewDataBinding, V extends BaseViewModel> extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseFragment.Callback {

    // TODO
    // this can probably depend on isLoading variable of BaseViewModel,
    // since its going to be common for all the activities
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private T viewDataBinding;
    private V viewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        performDependencyInjection();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        performDataBinding();
    }

    private void performDataBinding() {
        viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, getLayoutId());
        this.viewModel = viewModel == null ? getViewModel() : viewModel;
        viewDataBinding.setVariable(getBindingVariable(), viewModel);
        viewDataBinding.executePendingBindings();
    }



    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void requestPermissionsSafely(String[] permissions, int requestCode) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public boolean hasPermission(String permission) {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M ||
                checkSelfPermission(permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentAttached() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentDetached(String tag) {

    }

    public void hideKeyboard() {
        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    public void openActivityOnTokenExpire() {
        startActivity(LoginActivity.getStartIntent(this));
        finish();
    }

    public boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        return NetworkUtils.isNetworkConnected(getApplicationContext());
    }

    public void showLoading() {
        hideLoading();
        progressDialog = CommonUtils.showLoadingDialog(this);
    }

    public void hideLoading() {
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
    }

    public T getViewDataBinding() {
        return viewDataBinding;
    }

    /**
     * Override for set view model
     *
     * @return view model instance
     */
    public abstract V getViewModel();

    /**
     * Override for set binding variable
     *
     * @return variable id
     */
    public abstract int getBindingVariable();

    /**
     * @return layout resource id
     */
    public abstract
    @LayoutRes
    int getLayoutId();

    public void performDependencyInjection() {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
    }

}
```

This is the `login_activity.xml`:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="mypackage.LoginActivity">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="mypackage.LoginViewModel"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>
        <!-- Login progress -->
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/login_progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                        android:imeActionId="6"
                        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                    style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onServerLoginClick()}"

                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And this is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mypackage"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

    //firebase and gps
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$googlePlayServicesVersion"

    //Viewmodel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.lifecycle"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.lifecycle"

    // database
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$rootProject.roomDatabase"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomDatabase"

    // parser
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.gsonVersion"

    // dependency injection
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.dagger2Version"

    // reactive
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rootProject.rxjava2Version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rootProject.rxandroidVersion"


    //databinding
    annotationProcessor 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1'


    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: LoginActivityBinding or ActivityLoginBinding? It should be named it based on layout name not based on java class name.

Comment: My xml is named login_activity.xml and when I do control + b on it on the java file, the ide takes me to the layout xml.

Comment: are you getting any errors compiling the resources?  I've seen this behavior where none of the generated classes are available so long as there are any errors compiling the resources.

Comment: At compile time the only errors left are for LoginActivity/LoginActivityBinding. Even the dagger stuff seems to be getting generated fine.

Comment: try File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: I've done that several times, along with clean, and it hasn't helped.

Comment: Try manually delete `build` folders from all modules in the project.

Comment: Also, it's quite useful to increase the limit for reportable errors, like it said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35707088/3090951. Otherwise if there are more than 200 errors (which is quite easy reachable by Using of DataBinding) than the error report can be totally useless.

Comment: Sorry @AlexanderSkvortsov I replied to the wrong comment before, had two similar questions. The fix was to add `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.3"`

Comment: Have you fixed this with kotlin? if yes please share few classes of this structure, I was using same for java, and want to use for kotlin

Comment: This has changed significantly since I first posted that. Right now Android Studio will generate the binding class for your layouts and you call `LayoutNameBinding.bind` or `inflate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is meant to be a Kotlin project but I had just copied some Java files, I decided to search for this issue with Kotlin and turns out what I needed was this line `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.3"` on my dependencies.

Comment: If you use Android Studio >= 3.1 than `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.3"` is unnecessary.

Comment: I'm on 3.0.1 since 3.1 is not out yet.