# problems using databinding: val vs var and the use invalidateAll()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

This is actually 2 questions.

1. I noticed that databinding doesn't work if in the `Person` data class I set the `name` parameter to be `val` instead of `var`. The code will break with the following error:

> ```
> error: cannot find symbol
> import com.example.android.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBindingImpl;
>                                               ^
>   symbol:   class ActivityMainBindingImpl
>   location: package com.example.android.aboutme.databinding
> ```

Why does it happen?

2. Why do I need to call `invalidateAll()` in `doneClick()`? The documentation says that it "Invalidates all binding expressions and requests a new rebind to refresh UI". Isn't the purpose of databinding to connect data and views in such a way that an update to the data immediately updates the views?

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    val person = Person("Bob")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.person = person

        binding.apply {
            btnDone.setOnClickListener { doneClick(it) }
        }
    }

    private fun doneClick(view: View) {
        binding.apply {
            person?.nickname = etNickname.text.toString()
            invalidateAll()
            etNickname.visibility = View.GONE
            tvNickname.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            btnDone.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        hideKeybord(view)
    }

    private fun hideKeybord(view: View) {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

Person:

```
class Person(var name: String, var nickname: String? = null)
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="person"
            type="com.example.android.aboutme.Person" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            style="@style/NameStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={person.name}"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_nickname"
            style="@style/NameStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/what_is_your_nickname"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_done"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:text="@string/done" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_nickname"
            style="@style/NameStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={person.nickname}"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/star_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:contentDescription="@string/yellow_star"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/bio_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bio_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="@dimen/line_spacing_multiplier"
                android:text="@string/bio"
                android:textAppearance="@style/NameStyle" />

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: 1)you are not passing any nick name value in Person constructor. 2) invalidate all obviously used for update view after events but mostly related to update after network calls or any db related operations so can get latest updated data for view

Comment: @PJain 1. That's not the problem, I can make nickname have default value of "foo" and it will still crash with either `name` or `nickname` as `val` instead of `var`.

Comment: @qeh63 the error msg you posted is not the real error message. It's just a side effect of the real issue. Go through the entire logcat to find the real error msg. If you can't see the issue, not enough error messages might be displayed, then -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/35707088/1993204

Answer (score 17):

**Qustion 1:**

> I noticed that databinding doesn't work if in the Person data class I set the name parameter to be val instead of var.

> Why does it happen?

Because you're using [two-way databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way).

In your layout you have this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    style="@style/NameStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@={person.name}"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

The `@=` in `android:text="@={person.name}"`, specifically, tells databinding "I want to set the `TextView`'s text to the person's `name` value *and I want to update the person's `name` when the `TextView` text changes*".

When you use the `@=` databinding will look for a setter for the attribute you're assingning. In this case, it's looking for a setter for the `name` attribute on the `Person` class. In Kotlin, this means having a property named `name` that is a `var`.

If you do not intend to update the person's `name` attribute when the `TextView` changes (which I assume you don't, you'd generally do that with an `EditText`), then change that line to just `@` (`android:text="@{person.name}"`). Then you can make `name` a `val` because you're only *reading* from it for databinding.

---

**Question 2:**

> Why do I need to call invalidateAll() in doneClick()?

You actually don't ...

> The documentation says that it "Invalidates all binding expressions and requests a new rebind to refresh UI". Isn't the purpose of databinding to connect data and views in such a way that an update to the data immediately updates the views?

Yes, *but*: databinding is not magic. If the UI is to update *it must be told to do so* and changing your data does not magically tell databinding that it has to update. *Something* has to tell databinding that a) it's time to update and b) what it needs to update.

So what you have right now with `invalidateAll()` is the shotgun approach. You updated the one `nickname` field and then you yelled at databinding "hey, update everything!", so it rebinds *all* views based on the current state of `Person` which of course includes "nickname" so that view gets updated.

What you *want* to do is update *only* the fields that are bound to `nickname` because that is the one thing that changed and, preferably, you want to do it automatically when `nickname` changes. For that, you need to *observe* the state of the `nickname` field and *react* to it changing.

You can do this in a few ways:

1. [Use LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture)

In this approach you have the fields of the model you want to bind be `LiveData` objects (`val nickname = MutableLiveData<String>()`) and you add a `LifeCycleOwner` to the binding so it can observe the `LiveData` objects.

Databinding is set up to use `LiveData` so your xml does not need to change. But now the properties are *observable* and when you update the name on `Person` (`person?.nickname?.value = "New Nickname"`) databinding will be notified automatically and will update the state of the associated view.

You will not have to call `invalidateAll()`.

2. [Use Observable Fields](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#observable_fields)

This is conceptually the same as #1 but this came before `LiveData` was introduced. Nowadays you can consider this deprecated and use the `LiveData` approach, but I'll mention it for completeness.

Again, instead of having a regular property of type `String` you wrap that property in an *observable* data structure (`val nickname = ObservableString()`) that will notify databinding when the value has changed. Again, databinding is set up to work with this so you don't have to change your XML.

3. Use [Observable Objects](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#observable_objects)

With this option, you make your `Person` class (or preferably a `ViewModel`) extend `Observable` and manage notifying databinding yourself as the fields change. You would go this route if you have special logic that has to happen when updating some fields and a simple "set and notify" is not enough. This option is far more complicated and I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to read the docs to see how this option works. For the vast majority of cases you should be able to do what you need with option #1.

---

Parting thought on this line:

```
person?.nickname = etNickname.text.toString()
```

If you set up databinding correctly, *this should not be necessary*. :)
If you set up `etNickname` to use two-way binding and make `person.nickname` properly observable, *the `person.nickname` attribute will automatically update to the text value in `etNickname` when it changes*!

That is the beauty of databinding.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice, Great explanation

Comment: This could be a medium article! Great explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Val = Inmutable
   Var = mutable

Full answer 
[Val and Var in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200075/val-and-var-in-kotlin)

2. It's because the properties have no built-in mechanisms to notify the UI that they've changed. So you have to invoke it manually. A solution for this problem is using LiveData or MutableLiveData.