# Android Studio: Cannot find compiler error output

Tags: android, android-studio

According to [the second answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633956/android-studio-where-is-the-compiler-error-output-window), I can click on some icon within the build window in order to view the errors. The problem is that I cannot find the build window. There is a build variants window but no combination of changes that I can make in it will change anything

```
Error:(23, 10) error: ')' expected
Error:(27, 28) error: ';' expected
Error:(27, 54) error: ';' expected
Error:(31, 2) error: reached end of file while parsing
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

This is my program

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void myButtonListenerMethod() {
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout bgElement = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
                int color = ((ColorDrawable)bgElement.getBackground()).getColor();
                if (color == Color.RED) {
                    bgElement.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                } else {
                    bgElement.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

This is currently what the bottom toolbar in my android studio looks like

[image]

Comment: `setOnClickListener(` is missing a matching close parenthesis and semicolon

Comment: `Error:(23, 10) error: ')' expected` **is** the compiler error output

Answer (score 1):

You just  forgot close parenthesis and semicolon  **`);`** in `button.setOnClickListener()` method check it

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                RelativeLayout bgElement = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
                int color = ((ColorDrawable)bgElement.getBackground()).getColor();
                if (color == Color.RED) {
                    bgElement.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                } else {
                    bgElement.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: How can I see the compiler errors though? For when this comes up again.

Comment: @Jacob check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633956/android-studio-where-is-the-compiler-error-output-window

Comment: I posted a link to that one in my question. I explained there why it wasn't working for me.