# Android Studio 3.1 not showing build error details

Tags: android, error-log, android-studio-3.1

I have updated to Android Studio 3.1 and it doesn't show the details of error during compile time.
Suppose if I miss a semicolon somewhere or I haven't implemented a method of an interface, then it gives me this error all the time, but doesn't tell me what or where the error occurred!
**All error details were perfectly shown in Studio 3.0. How do I see them in 3.1?**

This is the message that I get every time an error occurs.

```
Compilation error. See log for more details
```

Comment: Are you looking into logs as well ??

Comment: @MezzyDroid Are you talking about LogCat?

Comment: yes exactly as most of the errors details are present in logCat ... and the above error "Compilation error. See log for more details" This points to the LogCat

Comment: No, there is nothing in LogCat!

Comment: @MezzyDroid These errors used to be in the 'Messages' tab in Studio 3.0, in 3.1 this tab is not present, so where to see these errors?

Comment: in 3.1 there is new tab named BUILD .... your messages will now be there !

Comment: @MezzyDroid That is the problem I am facing, I can see an error has occurred, but it is not showing me what error and where did it happen?

Comment: have you tried to see it in eventLog ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Where is the Compiler Error Output Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633956/android-studio-where-is-the-compiler-error-output-window)

Comment: @Mooga Please check the link thoroughly that you have sent, it is for Android Studio 1.x! A lot have changed since then !!!

Comment: This is absolutely horrible. Having that list removed in favor of a collapsed tree which even fails to show all errors is a big step back.

Comment: Sorry to rant, but AS is absolutely horrible when it comes to detecting errors. Just now, I had compile errors, but no error turned up among java compiler messages. Took me some half an hour to figure out I was stupid enough to forget implementing an interface yesterday when I finished my work late.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

There is a toggle button just below the build button that will show the verbose build logs. Tap that and you should be able to see errors like before AS 3.1.

[image: toggle button]

Comment: This tree view is horrible.

Comment: You save my time) Thanks!)

Comment: There is no toggle button in Android Studio 4.0.1

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if that was your problem, but you should find your errors right there:

[image]

So you have to disclosure all these lines to get your errors, at the very bottom. If anyone have a better way to do that, I'm looking for too.

Comment: **God this is awful**. Today that display even missed showing me an error which was present in the code.

Comment: To show the errors, you must manually do a Build / rebuild in menu. The errors are not shown when you just open the project.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this error since I update my PC and updated to 3.1+ ( which was done a the same time ).  I was getting the tree view list of successes/ fails but when a fail occurred it just stopped,  it didn't actually list the errors in the tree.  I had to view the full debug logs to find out where any issues were happening.

I believe the issue is down to a space in my user name,  Android Studio downloading the SDK to the default location of "C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk".  I spotted some of the config windows complaining about the space in that location,  so I've moved my SDK to "C:\Dev\Android\sdk" and now I see Java errors again at the bottom of the tree.