# Android Studio 4.0 not showing build error details

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

After upgrading Android Studio version to 4.0 there's no "toggle view" button in the Build Output window that switched to full output. So now there's no way now to see the error details. Is there a way aside from building the app in the terminal to see full error details?

[image: Build output]

Comment: see this post.i hope it's be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637589/android-studio-3-1-not-showing-build-error-details

Comment: @FarzadKamali thanks. Unfortunately there's no  toggle button in the Android Studio 4 now and the expanded tree on the left doesn't provide any details :(

Comment: Go to  File => Invalidate caches / restart. May be it will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Android Studio > Preferences > Compiler > Command-line Options:* --stacktrace --debug

Comment: Thank you , I have test in windows android 4.0,I can see my println() log in console, thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

It may sound ridiculous but I found the message window hided by the width of the Build output. There is an inconspicuous line on the right side. After moving it you can see message output
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can click on first line of the left side log tree to view all logs on right side detail view

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4F4P.png

Comment: But there is no detail of the error tree. Only one Error, right.

Comment: Unfortunately as @shohruhMaxmudov said - it doesn't show full description