# adding kotlin-kapt cause of getting Can not resolve symbol DaggerApplicationComponent error

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, dagger-2, dagger

I did not already have any problem with `Dagger` as far i don't add `Realm` in my project, after adding that on my project i expect i can build successful my project but i get this error now:

```
Can not resolve symbol DaggerApplicationComponent
```

i want to need `Realm` on my application and i can't remove that, but i dont get any other error on `Logcat` to know whats problem and i should be fix that and I'm not sure how can i resolve this problem

when i have this lines in build.gradle i dont have problem

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'
```

but after adding `Realm` i get

```
Configuration with name 'kapt' not found
```

error, and after adding `kotlin-kapt` to this file i get

```
Can not resolve symbol DaggerApplicationComponent
```

error, for example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Comment: I assume you have some build error which makes the annotation processing fail. Have you tried checking the build tab / compiler output?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce is this what you want to know that: http://paste.debian.net/1068972/ ?

Comment: Unfortunately this is just the other side of it aka gradle's error message (see the exception message saying you should check the compiler output for details :P `Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`) so you should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633956/android-studio-where-is-the-compiler-error-output-window/48005426#48005426

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I'm so sorry, http://paste.debian.net/1068977/  and  full debug link  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7m2B5VFsF8/

Comment: @EpicPandaForce could you know whats problem?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce removing Realm from project resolve my problem

Comment: It looks like you're using `annotationProcessor` scope for Dagger even though you're using `kapt`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188697/discussion-between-doldurma-and-epicpandaforce).

Answer (score 3):

Problem resolved, after change `annotationProcessor` to kapt